# Name based SSL Virtual Hosting ubuntu 16 and apache 2.4

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2, ssl

I have set up the name based hosting properly for port 80.

My question is, for port 443, if a name based site on my vhost does not have port 443 enabled or if I `a2dissite` a config for a site, the https version of the site seems to try to open that of another site on the server.

### More details

I set up site1.conf in sites available

```
<Virtualhost *:80>

ServerName www.site1.com
ServerAlias site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
.....

</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost *:443>

ServerName www.site1.com
ServerAlias site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
.....
SSLEngine On
... all other certificate params

</VirtualHost>
```

For site2.conf

```
<Virtualhost *:80>

ServerName www.site2.com
ServerAlias site2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
.....

</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost *:443>

ServerName www.site2.com
ServerAlias site2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
.....
SSLEngine On
... all other certificate params

</VirtualHost>
```

Works fine all together if both SSL are OK.

I decided to a2dissite site2.conf. If I open https ://www. site2.com, it throws an error that SSL config is only for www.site1.com meaning the a2dissite site2.conf did not disable the https part of the site2 but http :// www.site2.com opens the default root directory which is fine. How to I make sure https :// www.site2.com also shows the default apache root directory instead of using site1.com SSL and throwing an error?

Comment: Ever figure this one out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Not yet. I took on some course and I've not been able to do much on that. I will take a quick pick at it soon. Hopefully, I'm a bit smarter than I was then :D

Comment: I figured it out for me. I'm on Ubuntu 17 and might be a different version of apache, but it might be the same issue. I had multiple sites to configure. I was bringing them over from another server so they already had 443 virtual hosts. I was trying to configure the 2nd one first, but if the first site's {by conf file name) 443 virtual host failed, they all did. I commented out all of the 443 virtual host sections except the one I was working on and it fixed it.